Ease of Access OSK cannot unlock touch screen computer
Thank you in advance for any thoughts or assistance with a problem I have at work.
Situation:
I am not a system admin with my company and need to find a way to allow the On-Screen Keyboard to unlock a locked touchscreen Windows 10 computer (not a tablet). This is set to Ctrl + Alt + Del by the company GPO settings (group policy overview). There is no corrupted file or faulty installation and the PC's work just fine if I use a keyboard to unlock. However, any form of keyboard is not allowed and I need to find a work around.
Use Case:
Very hazardous work conditions that prevents the use of a keyboard and mouse.
Limitations:

Cannot use external mouse or keyboard in any way
Cannot install or use any external program (autohotkey, scripting software,etc)
Do not have admin rights in any fashion. This means I cannot change the security settings. I cannot even access UAC and simply turn off the lock screen
Multiple common solutions are inaccessible. I cannot use regedit or most executables. I have access to the Cmd line and powershell, but any function that requires admin privileges likely will not work
Local IT is aware but they do not have the ability to modify GPO settings

Attempted Solutions:

Hitting Ctrl + Alt + Del. Hitting Ctrl + AltR + Del. Ctrl + windows + Del. Ctrl + Alt + Esc, Ctrl + Alt + End, along with pretty much every other permutation possible that I researched
Modifying the Sticky Keys on and off to see if that would affect the commands
Tried changing the default keyboard language
No amount of swiping up, up, down, down, left, right, left, right, combinations will unlock
Not a tablet, so hitting the Power button plus other buttons does not apply
No icons nor menu selections available on lock screen. Nothing to interact with besides the Ease of Access On-Screen Keyboard


Is the issue the On Screen Keyboard offers no way to input the CTRL-ALT-DEL? Unfortunately, as this is a business environment, IT are the ones responsible for solving this. While it sounds as though you've tried local IT, SOMEONE has the ability to make changes, and if business demands certain functions (relaxed/different restrictions on these shop floor machines, for instance), IT must find a way to implement this. IT serves the org, not the other way around. Ultimately, you appear to be in the middle of what is not actually a technical issue.

"Do not have admin rights in any fashion." That might be an issue. Almost any solution that requires changes to system settings requires Admin privileges. It's an IT issue, not yours.

If not keyboard is allowed. How does the system even boot? Most modern computer systems cannot boot without a keyboard. Based on what you describe your problem cannot be solved without an Administrator

Appreciate the responses.
I agree as all 3 of the comments have said so far; this is an IT issue. And yes, someone has the power at some level to modify the settings, but our Org chart has about 12 levels depending on position (no, I'm not joking) so I have to work my way through each level the of the chain.
Executives won't accept "sorry, we can't build product for a year" as an excuse, so yes I'm in a conundrum and trying to solve a weird problem.

If there is a hard crash and the PC needs to be booted, we have to physically move the PC out of the hazardous chamber. Then, under safe conditions, we can plug a keyboard into it to unlock it. But since the GPO lockout time is set to something like 10 minutes, we can't be moving 50 PC's in and out throughout the day.
